# Animation of files moving from one folder to the other is what?

Tags: interaction-design, affordance, consistency, data-mapping, visibility

Consider the animation that appears when you drag and drop a bunch of files from one folder to another and you can see the files moving from the first folder to the second. Is that an example of any of these: visibility, affordance, mapping, consistency? Why, why not? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds a bit like you've been given an essay question and can't be bothered to do the research. Is there a specific UX problem you're trying to solve be adding (or removing) an animation?

Comment: @AndrewMartin This is not the case. I am trying to understand the differences between these concepts and while I know the definition of each of them I find it hard to apply that knowledge and distinguish between them in an actual real scenario, so I took an example of `feedback` from an article I was reading and decided to ask for clarification on whether any of the other main concepts I know of apply as well.

Comment: Plenty of terms in UX overlap and have 'soft edges' - there are cases to be made for the animation in relation to all of these terms depending on how you look at it. Is it telling you that a specific process is taking place? Is it telling you that the process isn't complete? Is it distracting you from noticing how long the process is taking?... Every different context you can think of will relate in different ways to the different terms. There isn't necessarily a concrete answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll discuss each term separately:

## Visibility

I haven't heard this term before, I'm guessing it comes from [David Hogue](http://www.givegoodux.com/visibility-5-principles-interaction-design-supercharge-ui-2-5/)? This is his definition:

> Good visibility, according to Hogue’s principles, means that obvious
>   prompts and cues are present, which:
>
> - Lead the user through an interaction.
> - Guide them through a series of tasks.
> - Indicate what possible actions are available to them.
> - Communicate the context of the situation.

Out of all of these, the animation meets the last point, as it communicates that the files are being moved, where the files came from and where they're going.

## Affordance

Depends on your definition. Don Norman defines them as "perceivable action possibilities". The animation doesn't meet this definition, as it doesn't communicate what actions you may take.

## Mapping

Depends on what definition you're using. Mapping is often used in the context of making diagrams, which isn't the case here. There's also the case of mental maps, where you try to come close to how a user understands concepts.

You could argue that you're mapping the move action to the physical movement of objects, which is illustrated by this move animation.

## Consistency

This really depends on the context you're designing in. If the move animation is commonly used on the platform, in other projects, or at least within your own project, then it's an example of consistency.